# Вывод числа от value до 0

Tags: javascript, html, css

После нажатия кнопки нужно сделать вывод в out числа от value input до 0
Должно выглядеть примерно так
4 3 2 1 0;

Решить нужно с помощью цикла

```
function t7() {
    let out = document.querySelector('.out-7');
    let a = ' ';
    let b = document.querySelector('.i-7');
    for (i = b.value; i >= 0; i--) {
        a += i + ' ';
    }
    out.innerHTML = a;
}

document.querySelector('.b-7').onclick = t7;
```

Comment: i забыли добавить a +=  i +' ';

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function t7() {
    let out = document.querySelector('.out-7');
    let a = ' ';
    let b = document.querySelector('.i-7').value;
    for (i = b; i >= 0; i--) {
        a += i + ' ';
    }
    out.innerHTML = a;
}

document.querySelector('.b-7').onclick = t7;
```

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 2):

Как вариант:

```
function t7() {
    const out = document.querySelector('.out-7');
    const field = document.querySelector('.i-7');
    const value = Number(field.value) || 0;
    const result = Array.from(Array(value + 1), (_, index) => index);
    
    out.innerHTML = result.reverse().join(' ');
}

document.querySelector('.b-7').onclick = t7;
```

Answer (score 0):

Я бы сделал при помощи массива

```js
function Decrease(val) {
  let str = [];
  for(let i = val; i >= 0; i--)
    str.push(i);
  return str.join(' ');
}

console.info(Decrease(10));
```